# What is the difference between "Average" and "Mediocre"

Tags: word-usage

I came across these two words and every time they confuse me. Please suggest me which one is used where and why.

Thank You!

Comment: It would certainly help your question if you actually **showed** that dictionary definitions may be recursive: [average=mediocre](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/average) | [mediocre=average](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/mediocre)

Comment: An average mathematician may or may not be mediocre. But an average is never mediocre.

Answer (score 3):

**Average** is a set of things added up and divided by the number of things in the set - in certain context it can be positive or negative or neither.

**Mediocre** always has a negative connotation - even when it means average.

So if something is measured in poor to excellent, depending on context, average may be great if excellent is impossible to achieve.

> *He was an average concert pianist, so he decided to become an excellent piano bar entertainer.*
>
> *They had two piano bar entertainers, of whom one was mediocre...*

But it is, for example, not a great thing to be of average intellect.

---

> **Average**
>   * A number expressing the central or typical value in a set of data, in particular the mode, median, or (most commonly) the mean, which is calculated by dividing the sum of the values in the set by their number.
>   * Mediocre; not very good.
>   ‘a very average director making very average movies’<sub>[Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/average)</sub>
>
> **Mediocre**
>   * Of only average quality; not very good.
>   ‘he is an enthusiastic if mediocre painter’
>   <sub>[Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/mediocre)</sub>

---

> **Mediocre**
>   Although some dictionaries accept the meaning of this word as “medium” or “average,” in fact its connotations are almost always more negative. When something is distinctly not as good as it could be, it is mediocre. If you want to say that you are an average student, don’t proclaim yourself mediocre, or you’ll convey a worse impression of yourself than you intend.<sub>[Common Errors in English Usage and More](https://brians.wsu.edu/2016/05/24/mediocre/)</sub>

Comment: I'll remove the downvote if you can be bothered to add some supporting material.

Answer (score 0):

‘Average’ is essentially a mathematical and statistical  term.  It denotes that some number or range of numbers is midway between the highest and lowest number.  If you have five steel tubes of length 1,2,3,4 and five metres in length, their average length is 1+2+3+4+5 [=15] divided by the number of tubes [5].  So the average is 3.  Strictly, this is the ‘mean’.  A different ‘middle’ is called the ‘median’ or midway point between the highest number (in our case, 3, but with larger numbers, these two types of average are rarely the same.  There is a third type of average, which is the most common number:  this is called the ‘mode’.

I explain this to show that at its core, averages have nothing to do with valuing things for good or ill.  ‘Mediocre’, by contrast, is entirely derogatory.  It carries a bit of a sneer with it.

In recent intensely competitive times, the usage of ‘average’ has been increasing used in a derogatory sense.  Politicians and sportsmen, not to mention competitors in game shows, have come to despise the average (the middle point between top and bottom, fastest and slowest, richest and poorest).   They are used to place people, communities in a variety of rank orders:  richest to poorest, best to worst country, school, student at mathematics,

So the odour of the word mediocre has increasingly infected the word ‘average’.

So, ‘mediocre’ is only and exclusively derogatory, slightly harsher than ‘ordinary’ and about the same as ‘nothing to write home about’.  ‘Average’ is better used in its strictly mathematical/statistical sense.  But you can use it in the sense of ‘mediocre’.

Comment: Is this not the exact same answer I gave, only with a lot more words?

Comment: My answer is broadly similar to yours, mplungjan.

Comment: I'd downvote for lack of supporting references if your rep exceeded 1000.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth how does one add the postnotice I see on the other answer _Some of the information contained in this post requires additional references. Please edit to add citations to reliable sources that support the assertions made here. Unsourced material may be disputed or deleted._ ?

Comment: @mplungjan  I'd hazard a guess that one has to have a moderator utility belt. But as you prove, it can be added as a comment.

Answer (score -2):

`Average` is something that `meets the standards`.

`Mediocre` is something that is `sub-standard`.

e.g. Messi's performance in 2017-18 la-liga season thus far (12 goals/ 13 appearances) has been `average` while Cristiano's performance in the same (2 goals/ 9 appearances) has been `mediocre`.

Comment: This gives a rough idea, but could mislead.  The use of the word ‘average’ is at root mathematical and statistical.  So its tone is essentially value neutral.  But the word ‘mediocre’ is always used in a derogatory sense.  Both indicate something in the middle.